# json values are not getting in the code in mobile jquery in phonegap

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am a iphone developer.Recently started working on phonegap and mobile jquery.I am not able to get the values from server  neither it shows in the programm please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>DEMO</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-   1.2.0.min.css" /> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script> 
<title>DEMO</title> 
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 

function LoginButton_onclick() { 
$.ajax({ 
type: "POST", 
document.write("hello"); 
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
dataType: "json", 
url: "http://182.72.192.18/webservicedemo/service.asmx/HelloWorld", 
data: '{}', 
success: function(msg) { 
jsonArray = $.parseJSON(msg.d); 
var $ul = $( '<ul id="details">' ); 
for(i=0; i < jsonArray.length; i++) 
{ 
$("#details").append('<li id="'+i+'" name="head" >'+jsonArray[i].name+'</li>' ); 
} 
$('#details').listview('refresh'); 
}, 
error: function(msg) { 
alert("Error"); 
} 
}); 

} 


</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<div data-role="page" id="Page1"> 
<h1>DEMO PAGE</h1> 

<div id="DEMO"> 
<input id="LoginButton" type="button" value="GET DATA" onclick="LoginButton_onclick()" />       </div> 

<div id="divList" data-role="content"> 
<ul id="details" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"></ul> 
</div> 

</div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First off try wrapping it in `$(document).bind('pageinit', function(){})`

Next, make sure you are using data role attributes as per the JQM specification.

Try changing your event handler to:

`$("#LoginButton").on("click", function(){});`

Comment: can't i do it on button click@benM

Comment: Ive edited my original post for another thing for you to try. Rather than using html attributes to bind event handlers do it all in your javascript.

Comment: i have tried not getting any result shows error..i am new in html that's why not able to figure out what kind of error.:(